# How to compute the probability of sum of $5$ digits number to be equal to $23$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For example, $26843$ makes $2+6+8+4+3 = 23$.
Let's say I want to encode my book with number $23$ as my pattern that shows the intactness of my book in any new print. I also do not declare this but let's say I also mentioned the number $23$ out of context in my book for curious readers. If someone realize years later that the sum of the digits of the number of all the letters in my book is equal to $23$.

How likely s/he can think of this can occur by chance?

What is the general way of calculating this for any other number?

Comment: Big Hint: [Stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question can be reduced to the well-known problem of spreading $n$ balls in $m$ bins provided that the capacity of a bin is $p$ balls. The number of ways to do this is:

$$N (n,m,p)=\sum_{i\ge0}(-1)^i\binom mi \binom{n-i (p+1)+m-1}{m-1}.$$

With this at hand the answer to the question is
$$\frac {N (23,5,9)-N (23,4,9)}{90000}=\frac {6000-480}{90000}=\frac {23}{375}.
$$

The term $N(23,4,9)$ here counts the "5-digit" numbers which starts with $0$ (such as $06485$), $90000$ is the overall number of 5-digit numbers.

Comment: This is the correct general formula, but it's worth noting for clarity that this excludes sequences like $0+6+4+8+5=23$ since "06485" is a four digit number, not a five digit number. If we were looking at all length 5 sequences drawn from 0-9 and sum 23 it would be 6000/100000 instead of your 5520/90000.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I thought the term  $N(23,4,9)$ is self-explanatory but now I will add the explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the clear formula. Do you know of any R function or a web app that may run this?

Comment: @entropy I used Mathematica for the computation. WA also works: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%3D23;m%3D5;p%3D9;Sum(-1)%5Ei+(binom(m,i))+(binom(n-i(p%2B1)%2Bm-1,m-1)),+i+from+0+to+floor+(n%2F(p%2B1))

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

So using the stars and bars method, I usually use $1$s and $0$s. So your case above we can express it as:

$$110111111011111111011110111=23$$

So we can use combinatorics by: ${23+4 \choose 4}=17550$

Edit just to clarify: The ones and zeros do not matter you can use any symbol you would like, it basically means if you can list one scenario with ones/zeros like the one above because $2$ is two ones, then use a zero to separate it, then next you had $6$ so I used six ones and separated by another zero etc etc! Hope you can see where I got the pattern from. Then we do: $${\text{number of ones and zeros} \choose \text{number of zeros}}$$

which is a combinatoric, for which there is an easy formula for it (google it).

For another example we have $9+9+1+1+3=23$, so this pattern would be:

$$111111111011111111101010111=23$$

Again we have number of ones is $23$, number of zeroes is $4$ so the answer is the same before. Not too mathsy but if you think about it all patterns are made up this way by changing the positions of ones and zeroes try it yourself! So there are $17550$ different number like this!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you mind explaining this for a non-mathematician. Not sure why did you use 1 and 0. Can you write a formula based on my specific example? and Can you give another example for another number to be clear?  thanks

Comment: Think about your question from the opposite direction. Rather than starting with 5 digits and thinking about what they add up to, start with 23 and think about how you could divide it into five nonzero parts. The "stars and bars" method that someone else linked to on wikipedia is the typical way to count up the number of ways of dividing N identical objects into K nonempty subsets, but there's a little more to your question, since the K=5 subsets need to not only be nonempty, but also have size at most 9.